# Разделитель между годом и месяцами в указании срока

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая или союз "и" в следующих выражениях?

> Является участником 2 года 10 месяцев

> Участник в течение 2 лет 10 месяцев

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если форма записи допускает изменение, а сроки участия не стремятся к бесконечности, можно было бы перейти на одну единицу измерения: *34 месяца, 34 месяцев (34 мес.)*.

Обе фразы допустимы, а союз необязателен и даже излишен для такого справочного сообщения.

Comment: Замена на кол-во месяцев не является приемлемой. Всё-таки в годах и месяцах измерять удобнее. Это из профиля участника сайта информация. Правильно ли я понял, что запятая тоже не нужна? [Сейчас она используется](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile).

Comment: «15 час. 30 мин.»  Здесь разве требуется какой-либо знак? Это одна величина. Как можно её разбивать? Разбить на части запятой — будет перечисление.

Comment: действительно. Я как-то не подумал о таком очевидном случае с часами и минутами.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел в Википедии ([Единицы измерения времени](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8#.D0.93.D0.BE.D0.B4.2C_.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.81.D1.8F.D1.86.2C_.D0.BD.D0.B5.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BB.D1.8F)) пример записи временно́го интервала – без запятых и без союзов:

**13 ч 53 мин 20 с**

По этому принципу ваши предложения должны быть написаны так:

**Является участником 2 года 10 месяцев.**

**Участник в течение 2 лет 10 месяцев.**

Answer (score 0):

По правилу пишется так:

Является участником 2 года 10 месяцев.
Участник в течение 2 лет 10 месяцев.

Comment: Если Вам известно правило, хорошо бы привести ссылку на него.