# Знаки препинания между единицами измерения: ставится ли запятая и влияет ли на это союз ("и")?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, числительные, однородные-члены

Уже обсуждался вопрос того, ставится ли запятая между единицами измерения времени (см. [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/434827/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0)). При прочих равных — нет ("13 ч. 53 мин. 20 с."; "является участником 2 года 10 месяцев" и т. д.). А как быть, когда употреблён союз ("и", "да"), не становятся ли тогда числительные однородными членами предложения? Почему? Где найти это правило (что запятая не ставится между единицами измерения)?

*На это у него ушло 2 года(,) 10 месяцев(,) 5 дней(,) 13 часов(,) 53 минуты и 20 секунд.*

*Купил 1 тонну(,) 50 килограммов и 200 граммов огурцов.*

*Залез на высоту 200 метров(,) 50 сантиметров и 8 миллиметров.*

Comment: Как числительное, записанное цифрами, буквенно-цифровая форма — всегда единое число. Меры принято записывать в сокращённом варианте: искусственные конструкции бывают хороши только в меру.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Грамота.ру" в итоге ответила, что **запятые НЕ требуются** и наличие союза "и" на их постановку никак не влияет (см. [Грамоту.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=309599)).

Поэтому верно так.

*На это у него ушло 2 года 10 месяцев 5 дней 13 часов 53 минуты и 20 секунд.*

*Купил 1 тонну 50 килограммов и 200 граммов огурцов.*

*Залез на высоту 200 метров 50 сантиметров и 8 миллиметров.*